# django1.9 after installation is not recognised by the command prompt

Tags: python, django

**PROBLEM**

Even after installation of django, typing the command django-admin --version shows up the message failed to create the process.

**what I've done**

- I have installed python version3.6.1 ,pip version 9.0.1 ,easy_install version28.0.1 and then installed django version 1.9 using easy_install.
- In the Environment variables of mycomputer I've set the PATH both to python folder and the scripts folder.

Comment: are you trying to view the django-admin version? use `django-admin.py version` or `python manage.py version`

Comment: yes as a confirmation for django installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the hang .The problem is with windows , not the installation process. For the same task the commands doesn't remain the same in everyone's case as changing the command from django-admin --version to C:>path to installation directory>python django-admin-script.py --version from the script directory worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) or similar to manage your python packages on a per-project basis. Then you can create a new virtualenv and install a clean version of django 1.9.

`pip install virtualenv`

`virtualenv env -p path/to/python3.6`

`source env/bin/activate`

`pip install django==1.9`

Comment: but I'm looking ahead to use pycharm IDE and I  followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK   video tutorial's django installation instructions